# Reacting to calendar events in the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Is there a way that my app can be notified when a calendar event (a meeting, whatever) starts?

Comment: only one way is receive events and build into u app own schedule

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can could achieve this using the [Event Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/FetchingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004775-SW1).